# how to get detail information of a exclude constraint in PostgreSQL 10?

Tags: postgresql, constraints, information-schema

I'm developing a SQL client tool of PostgreSQL, and want to support the EXCLUDE constraint feature in the tool, how to get detail information of a exclude constraint in PostgreSQL 10?

I expect to get the detail information of EXCLUDE constraint, like name / index method/ elements / comment / buffer / where / deferrable / deferred etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use this example:

```
CREATE TABLE xclude (id integer NOT NULL, EXCLUDE (id WITH =));
```

You can use this query:

```
SELECT c2.relname,
       i.indisvalid,
       pg_catalog.pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid, 0, true),
       pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(con.oid, true),
       contype,
       condeferrable,
       condeferred,
       c2.reltablespace
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_index i ON c.oid = i.indrelid
   JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class c2 On i.indexrelid = c2.oid
   LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_constraint con ON (conrelid = i.indrelid AND conindid = i.indexrelid AND contype IN ('x'))
WHERE c.oid = 'xclude'::regclass;
```

The result:

```
relname              | xclude_id_excl
indisvalid           | t
pg_get_indexdef      | CREATE INDEX xclude_id_excl ON xclude USING btree (id)
pg_get_constraintdef | EXCLUDE USING btree (id WITH =)
contype              | x
condeferrable        | f
condeferred          | f
reltablespace        | 0
```